# h.265 can't be played in browser

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am building a custom video player, but it seems like the `<video />` tag can't play H.265 files. I compressed files with ffmpeg, but I can't play them in the web. Even when I redirect to the source the browser can't play the file. Is there a way to play the files or build a custom player that is able to play it? I read that it is able to run h265 in some browsers. Is there a way to process the file on the device and play it then?

Comment: _Of the desktop browsers only Microsoft Edge (version 16 and later) and Safari (version 11 and later) support H.265._ -- Source: https://flussonic.com/doc/video-playback/playing-h-265/

Comment: See [this format compatibility table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support) on Wikipedia, and consult MDN's [Creating a cross-browser video player](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player) for ideas how to support multiple browsers by providing format options, if a single format does not cover all of the browsers you wish to target.

Comment: I know that only some browsers support it. That's why I asked if there is a way to build your own html tag that could play h265

Comment: It's recommended to transfer the video to H.264 format for a better user experience.